# From mysqli_result Object to string

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have a mysqli_result Object doing this:

```
    $mysqli->real_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `level` > 2");
    $user_list = $mysqli->use_result();
    print_r($user_list); die();
```

Doing so, the print_r give me:

```
mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 6 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 0 [type] => 1 )
```

Later im just using `while ($row = $user_list->fetch_assoc())` to parse all the content. The think is before doing the while I want to retrieve the `num_rows` from the mysqli_result Object but doing just $user_list['num_rows'] does not work:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array

Comment: @YourCommonSense That comment doesn't make sense. mysqli is ok to use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the `num_rows` using the `$result->num_rows`

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("")) {

    /* determine number of rows result set */
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
}
```

After getting `num_rows` you can fetch it.

Comment: You can use that. You have to store the query exec result in one variable and you have to get num_rows for that variable. Please look into my code how i am using it. Try it once.

Answer (score 3):

Does `$user_list->num_rows` work?

Comment: So, in your example, if you replace your print_r line with that it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, in my case it works :)

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `level` > 2";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
     var_dump($rows);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$mysqli->real_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `level` > 2");
$user_list = $mysqli->use_result();
echo $user_list->num_rows;
```